# Group by COUNT in codeigniter make database error

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following code:

```
public function date_range_customers($params){

       $start_app_date = $params['start_app_date'];
       $end_app_date   = $params['end_app_date'];           


       $this->load->database();
       $this->db->select(
        'COUNT(tbl_appointment.id) AS total',            
        'tbl_customer.cus_name',
        'tbl_customer.cus_email',
        'tbl_customer.cus_mobile'
      );   
      $this->db->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.id = tbl_appointment.customer_id','inner');
      $this->db->join('tbl_transaction','tbl_transaction.app_id = tbl_appointment.id','inner');
      $this->db->where("app_date BETWEEN '$start_app_date' AND '$end_app_date' AND trans_type_id=1");
      $this->db->group_by('total','desc');
      $query = $this->db->get('tbl_appointment');
```

When I try to group by 'total' there is error occurred as follows,

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1056 Can't group on 'total'
>
> SELECT COUNT(tbl_appointment.id) AS total FROM `tbl_appointment` INNER
>   JOIN `tbl_customer` ON `tbl_customer`.`id` =
>   `tbl_appointment`.`customer_id` INNER JOIN `tbl_transaction` ON
>   `tbl_transaction`.`app_id` = `tbl_appointment`.`id` WHERE `app_date`
>   BETWEEN '2018-01-01' AND '2018-04-30' AND `trans_type_id` = 1 GROUP BY
>   `total`
>
> Filename: C:/wamp64/www/theme/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: replace your select statement with `$this->db->select('COUNT(tbl_appointment.id) AS total, tbl_customer.cus_name, tbl_customer.cus_email, tbl_customer.cus_mobile', false);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not group by an aggregated  column

but could be you need  an order_by  for total desc

```
   $this->load->database();
   $this->db->select(
    'COUNT(tbl_appointment.id) AS total',            
    'tbl_customer.cus_name',
    'tbl_customer.cus_email',
    'tbl_customer.cus_mobile'
  );   
  $this->db->join('tbl_customer', 'tbl_customer.id = tbl_appointment.customer_id','inner');
  $this->db->join('tbl_transaction','tbl_transaction.app_id = tbl_appointment.id','inner');
  $this->db->where("app_date BETWEEN '$start_app_date' AND '$end_app_date' AND trans_type_id=1");
  $this->db->group_by(array('cus_name','cus_email','cus_mobile'));     
  $this->db->order_by('total','desc');
  $query = $this->db->get('tbl_appointment');
```

and for this you should add  in  group by the non aggrefated column you have in select

Comment: Note that you need atleast need PHP 5.4.0 before `$this->db->group_by(['cus_name','cus_email','cus_mobile'] ); ` can work. otherwise you need to replace it with `$this->db->group_by(array('cus_name','cus_email','cus_mobile')); `

Comment: @RaymondNijland   .. correct  .. answer  updated  with old array format  . many thanks

Comment: @scaisEdge Thanku so much..It is working fine.but i when i  try to display it in view file(codeignitor),cus_name,cus_email,cus_phone dispalys as undefined index.

Comment: <?php
                foreach ($date_range_customers as   $date_range_customers){ 
                    echo $date_range_customers['cus_name'];
                    echo $date_range_customers['cus_email'];
                    echo $date_range_customers['cus_mobile'];
                    echo $date_range_customers['total'];
                }

                ?>

Comment: what wrong here?how can I display those data on view?